# How to insert an object into a set

Tags: c++

I'm trying to insert an object into a set, and I overloaded the '<' operator:

```
class domino {

public:
domino();
domino(int l, int r);

void SetRightDots(int rightDots);
int GetRightDots() const;

void SetLeftDots(int leftDots);
int GetLeftDots() const;

string toString() const;
bool operator<(const domino &d) const;
bool operator==(const domino &d) const;

private:
int leftDots;
int rightDots;

};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
set<domino> sd=set<domino>();
set<domino>::iterator ite;

for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    for (int j = i; i <= 6; j++) {
        sd.insert(domino(i,j));
    }
}

}
```

but I still get the following error:

/home/joju/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `domino::domino(int, int)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o: In function `std::less::operator()(domino const&,  domino const&) const':

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236: undefined reference to  `domino::operator<(domino const&) const'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Do you actually have an implementation of the `domino` class ? (p.s. suggest naming the class Domino)

Comment: You need to link the implementation of `domino`, do you implement it in `domino.cpp`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler complains that the implementation of the constructor taking two integers is not found. You need to actually define that constructor even if you leave it blank.

For example:

```
domino::domino(int a, int b) { /* do something */ }
```

Outside of your class or you can define it directly in the class:

```
class domino {
    /* stuff */
    domino(int l, int r) { /* do something */ }
    /* stuff */
};
```